# Append the address bar

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to display the details of  specific project based on the parameter i.e id passed on the url. But i don't want the page and the varialble be displayed on the url and wish to use only the parameter to do further funtioning by using `$_GET['id']`. My code somewhat works this way....

```
<a href="details.php?id=1">Get Detail</a>
```

address bar is :: `localhost/project/details.php?id=1456`
can i get something like :: `localhost/project/1456`

thank you.

Comment: Use .htaccess redirections

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi i am very new in this.... could you provide an example of it please... it would be very helpful. Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file in your project folder and copy these lines into .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/project/([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/your_file_to_run.php?id=$1 [L]
```

In your php file **your_file_to_run.php** you can use $_GET['id'] to get the value of id

Comment: if i write localhost/project/1 on address bar, it is showing page not found. while i was hoping to get id on my other page. m i doing sth wrong?? i have copied the code and did everything.

Comment: Whats the path of .htacccess file in your project that you created

Comment: file name should be .htaccess; Its a Apache configuration file. File name should preceded with dot

Comment: I have updated the .htaccess code . Please use it again. It will work now

Answer (score 0):

I assume You are using Apache. So enable mod-rewrite and put `.htaccess` file into your web root directory.

To configure frendly linka You need smth like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
--EMPTY LINE OR FILE WILL FAIL--
```

This file should reside in project dir
Empty line is important!

Comment: could you explain  ^view/(.)/(.)/(.*).html$ index.php?catid=$1&id=$2&t=$3 [NC] so that i can use/alter it according to my neccessity. m all confused

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your project directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\d]+)$ details.php?id=$1
```

Comment: first you have to put this `.htaccess` in project directory then whenever you call `localhost/project/1456` it will rewrite your request to details.php file it must present in project directory.